# What does 'crab' mean when describing a person?

Tags: meaning, adjectives, ambiguity

In the Netflix series Mindhunter there is a scene where a person is asked to give their opinion about a female colleague. They reply with 'she's a crab'. I am sure that this is meant in a negative way but I don't know what it means exactly.
Is it somewhat related to 'crab apple'? Meaning the person is sour in a way.

Comment: Perhaps she is [**crabby**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/crabby). Either that, or it means she is devious – moves sideways.

Comment: In the British armed services, saying someone is a 'Crab' means they are a member of the Royal Air Force.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey very interesting to know, but I doubt it was the case here. she was an elementary school teacher

Comment: It's related to the sea creature with the snapping claws.

Comment: @Hot Licks - you don't say!

Comment: Yes, crabby. A crab is someone who often complains.

Comment: @YosefBaskin the noun could come from [**crab³**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/crab) *VERB Grumble about something petty.*